# restart reading data in onErrorResumeNext when BleAlreadyConnectedException is encountered

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, android-bluetooth, rxandroidble

I am using [RXAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) library to connect and read data from the BLE device. I have set the `establishConnection` function to `true` i.e. auto-connect to true. when the `BleAlreadyConnectedException` is occurring I want to capture that exception and restart the flow of reading data because every time disposing and connecting to BLE device is creating issues. so better to keep the connection alive and re-read the data.

In `onErrorResumeNext` i to re-call the functions writeStatus, readModelInfo,getReadings and so on. Now sure how would I achieve it.

```
   device.establishConnection(true)
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> {
            rxBleConnection.discoverServices();
            mRxBleConnection = rxBleConnection;
            return Observable.just(rxBleConnection);
        })
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(TSDictionary.BATTERY_LEVEL,NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP).flatMap(it->it))
        .flatMap(bytes -> writeStatus())
        .flatMap(bytes->readModelInfo(bytes))
        .flatMap(bytes -> getReadings(bytes))
        .doOnNext(data->initializeErrorHistory(data))
        .flatMap(data->getSequenceSize())
        .flatMap(length ->getOperationInfo(length))
        .doOnNext(data->initializeOperationInfo(data))
        .onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<? extends ArrayList<Map<Integer, TSDictionaryMetaData>>>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<? extends ArrayList<Map<Integer, TSDictionaryMetaData>>> apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {

                if(throwable instanceof  BleAlreadyConnectedException){

                    // i want to RECALL/restart the  function call 
                    // writeStatus ,readModelInfo,getReadings, initializeErrorHistory
                    // getSequenceSize , getOperationInfo, initializeOperationInfo
                }
                return null;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(data -> {

        }, e -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `onErrorResumeNext` closer to the connection code.

```java
device.establishConnection(true)
.doOnNext(rxBleConnection -> {
    rxBleConnection.discoverServices();
    mRxBleConnection = rxBleConnection;
})
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
     if (throwable instanceof BleAlreadyConnectedException) {
        return Observable.just(mRxBleConnection);
     }
     return Observable.error(throwable);
})
.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> 
     rxBleConnection.setupNotification(TSDictionary.BATTERY_LEVEL,
         NotificationSetupMode.QUICK_SETUP)
    .flatMap(it->it)
)
.flatMap(bytes -> writeStatus())
.flatMap(bytes->readModelInfo(bytes))
.flatMap(bytes -> getReadings(bytes))
.doOnNext(data->initializeErrorHistory(data))
.flatMap(data->getSequenceSize())
.flatMap(length ->getOperationInfo(length))
.doOnNext(data->initializeOperationInfo(data))
.subscribe(data -> {

}, e -> {
    e.printStackTrace();
});
```

Comment: I have a `onError` block and my `BleAlreadyConnectedException` goes to that rather than in `retry` hence this isn't working?  any idea why

Comment: That exception may happen way before `writeStatus` thus it is not part of the retry process. In this case, try using `retry(...)` in place of `onErrorResumeNext` in your original example.

Comment: if I keep `retry` in the outer section (original one) then retry tries to reconnect as `establishConnection` is throwing `BleAlreadyConnectedException ` so rather than reusing `retry` is trying to make a new connection.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want cache the connection and skip `establishConnection`?

Comment: Yes, this way i can reuse it